# Dynamic programming script for the best way to sum numbers

Tags: python, dynamic-programming

I'm trying to learn some basic stuff in dynamic programming, but I got stuck in the following problem:

given as input an integer `sum` and a list of positive integers `numbers`, return the list made of the smallest amount of number belonging to `numbers` that sum up to `sum`.

Hope this is clear, I'll give you three examples:

if `sum = 10` and `numbers = (2, 3, 5)` should return `[5, 5]`;
if `sum = 0` and `numbers = (2, 3, 5)` should return `[]`;
if `sum = 10` and `numbers = (3)` should return `False`.

```
def bestsum(sum, numbers, memo={}):
    if sum == 0:
        return []
    elif sum < 0:
        return False
    else:
        if sum not in memo:
            shortest_combination = False
            for number in numbers:
                remainder = sum - number
                combination = bestsum(remainder, numbers)
                if combination != False:
                    combination.append(number)
                    if shortest_combination == False or len(combination) < len(shortest_combination):
                        shortest_combination = combination
            memo[sum] = shortest_combination
        return memo[sum]
```

I do not put `memo` as an input of my recursive call of `bestsum`, since it worked with other dynamical programs I did before. Even if I add it, however, the script doesn't work, it update the `memo` even when I do not do that explicitly. Adding a `copy.copy` or actually inserting my `memo` as input doesn't help. Maybe the problem is that I still miss how variables *live* in my memory when I call different and maybe recursively other functions.

Comment: Two quick points. First, don't know variables keywords. That means you should rename your sum variable. Second, the function seems to either return a list or a bool. I would tighten that up.

Comment: Possible dup of [“Least Astonishment” and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument).

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument)

Comment: @bdempeL "don't know variables keywords"?

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes to the codebase and added some comments, but I kept most of them:

```py
def bestsum(sum, numbers, memo={}):
    if sum == 0:
        return []
    elif sum < 0:
        return False
    else:
        if sum not in memo:
            for number in numbers:
                remainder = sum - number
                shortest_combination = bestsum(remainder, numbers, memo)
                if shortest_combination != False:
                    # Good news! We found a valid path from `sum` to the end
                    if (
                        sum not in memo
                        or len(memo[sum]) > len(shortest_combination) + 1
                    ):
                        # Either there's no entry in memo for `sum` yet
                        # Or we've found a better subpath than the current one
                        currently_best_combination = shortest_combination.copy()
                        currently_best_combination.insert(0, number)
                        memo[sum] = currently_best_combination
            if sum in memo:
                # Return value if we've found a valid path 
                return memo[sum]
            else:
                # Return false if not
                return False
        else:
            # If sum is already in `memo`, it's already the optimal way
            return memo[sum]
```

```
numbers = [2, 3, 5]
print(bestsum(10, numbers))
# [5, 5]

numbers = [2, 3, 5]
print(bestsum(0, numbers))
# []

numbers = [3]
print(bestsum(10, numbers))
# False
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the problems laid out in the comments (namely mutable default argument, using the name of a builtin as a variable name) you would also run afoul of shallow copies if you were to pass on the `memo` argument (EDIT: actually come to think of it, that would happen regardless..).

The quickest fix for all of the problems mentioned with minimal changes would probably get you this

```
def bestsum(s, numbers, memo=None):
    if memo is None:
        memo = {}
    if s == 0:
        return []
    elif s < 0:
        return False
    else:
        if s not in memo:
            shortest_combination = False
            for number in numbers:
                remainder = s - number
                combination = bestsum(remainder, numbers, memo)
                if combination != False:
                    combination = combination.copy()
                    combination.append(number)
                    if shortest_combination == False or len(combination) < len(shortest_combination):
                        shortest_combination = combination
            memo[s] = shortest_combination
        return memo[s]
```

(this is not to say that this is the most elegant way of going about it, more of a direct fix for your code)

As for how I would do it:

```
def bestsum(s, numbers):
    sums = {0:[]}
    while(s not in sums and len(sums)>0):
        sums = {k+n:l+[n] for k,l in sums.items() for n in numbers if k+n<=s}
    if(s not in sums):
        return None
    else:
        return sums[s]
```